# Knocking noise when turning at full lock/opposite lock?

Tags: ford, noise, focus, steering

I have noticed that I have a knocking noise when I turn full lock or full opposite lock. The noise is a single knock as I reach lock and then another knock as I start turning back. I will intermittently get the same sound when accelerating hard/braking hard. The noise originates in the front right - presumably from the wheel.

Since I have recently [had a spring break on the left side of the car](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/8550/4339), I have checked this on the right side and the spring looks fine. The car in question is a 2001 Ford Focus.

Any idea what this could be?

Comment: I don't know that it is *completely* pertinent here, but could you include your vehicle make/model/year? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually turned out to be the upper strut mount being heavily worn, replacing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it could be something wrong with your steering pump. Especially if this mostly happens when you have just started the car (cold engine) and are driving very slowly.

Edit: if you have a steering fluid leak, this could be causing the steering pump to grind / knock. Try checking your steering fluid level and fill it up if it's running low. Then take it in to get it inspected - you may need a new pump, or at least to patch the leak.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the ball joints and tierod ends and control arm bushings. I have seen a lot of bad balljoints knock when the wheels hit the stops. I have also seen bad control arm bushings knock with acceleration and braking. Don't let it go for long without having it checked. If a ball joint or tierod separates you will loose control and your ability to steer.

Answer (score 0):

I think its the Drop Links on one side or maybe even both side of the front suspension . Cheap and easy to replace.

Answer (score 0):

I get noises from my wheels on full lock, and I've worked out it is the mudflaps I fitted myself, which are slightly out of position, and catch on the tyres. The noise echoes through the bodywork.

It might be worth verifying that nothing is touching the tyre (either side) when you're on full lock.

Answer (score 0):

The knocking noise you are hearing on full lock is CV joints.

Replace both sides at the same time, usually under £200 fitted.

Good Luck

Comment: Although CV joints can knock like that, the OP has already stated that it is the upper strut mount.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you have to get these things checked.
It could be a bad cv joint, it could be strut tops, it could be tie rod ends. Usually here we just run through a list of potentials, can’t diagnose without the lot of it in front of you though... pretty much.